# Как поменять url текущей страницы в Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Мне нужно сменить url страницы с:

```
driver.get(https://vk.com/al_feed.php)
... <-- Тут он делает некоторые действия
```

на:

```
 ... <-- Тут он всё сделал
https://vk.com/im
```

Comment: я немного ошибся при написаний, но суть понятна

Comment: вот как раз насчёт ясности сути — есть очень большие сомнения. впрочем, я могу ошибаться, и для профессионалов всё ясно как белый день.

Answer (score 1):

делаете тоже самое, что и в первом случае

```py
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/al_feed.php')
... ваш код ...
driver.get(url='https://vk.com/im')
```